# Extract all month in one coulmn from Date

Tags: mysql

I have a Date field in my table `Kot_items`. How to extract all in month name if not present month in Database?

```
select  distinct month(Tran_date) as mon
from Kot_items
```

Data in Databases

```
MON  monthname
    1          jan
    2          feb
    3          mar
```

Excepted Result

```
MON  monthname
1       jan
2       feb
3       mar
4       Apr
5       mar
6       june
7       july
8       Aug
9       Sep
10      Oct
11      nov
12      Dec
```

**update post::**

form this query::

select year(tran_date) as yearnumber,
QUARTER(tran_date) as quarternumber,
month(tran_date) as mon
from KOT_Items

```
yearnumber  quarternumber   mon 
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           4
```

Excepted Result to like

```
yearnumber  quarternumber   mon 
2014    1           1   
2014    1           2   
2014    1           3   
2014    2           3   
2014    2           4   
2014    2           5   
2014    3           6   
2014    3           7   
2014    3           8   
2014    4                9  
2014    4           10  
2014    4           11  
2014    4           12
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a table that has all the months in it?

Comment: As am new to mysql i dono how to do ??

Comment: Any Idea for above update post as newbie i cant able to find any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a table that has all the months in it. You can then use an outer join between this table and your transaction table.

```
CREATE TABLE months (mon INT, monthname CHAR(3)) AS
SELECT 1, 'Jan'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Feb'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'Mar'
...
SELECT 12, 'Dec'
```

If you can't do that, you can use a UNION subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS mon, 'Jan' AS monthname
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Feb'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 'Mar'
    ...
    SELECT 12, 'Dec') AS months
LEFT JOIN Kot_items AS i ON months.mon = MONTH(i.tran_date)
```

This can then be joined with your transaction table.

For the year, quarters, and months, do:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) AS yearnumber, 1 as quarternumber, 1 as mon
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 1, 3
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 2, 4
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 2, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 2, 6
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 3, 7
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 3, 8
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 3, 9
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 4, 10
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 4, 11
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 4, 12
```

If you use the `months` table I showed above, you can simply add a `quarternumber` column to the table. To make a table for the current year, you can use a query like:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), quarternumber, mon
FROM months
```

Comment: but if i use with u r idea  i had get datatype as Decimal fro mon,and string for monthname y cant it cant in Date Datatype

Comment: Not sure I understand the question (please write whole words, this isn't IM or twitter). Dates are not good for this because they have a specific year and day in them, you want the months for any year.

Comment: And i had a another problem now i get all month but as like above can i extract from date filed even year,months,quarter that have no in the table.

Comment: `select month(date_sub(NOW(), interval 12 month)) union select month(date_sub(NOW(), interval 11 month)) and so on`

Comment: is its possible to give full code??please it useful to learn from u

Comment: Just keep repeating 10 month, 9 month and so on until you have all the months of the year. I think you learn better by figuring this out yourself, not by copying code.

Comment: k fine i will try and say u

Comment: select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH))
union  select month(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH))
ya i got but this result will be provide a month but i want like above Update post

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT MONTH(Trans_date) as mon, MONTHNAME(Tran_date) as monthname FROM Kot_items ;
```

[From here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

**All months**

```
SELECT 1 as mon, 'January' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 2 as mon 'February' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 3 as mon 'March' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 4 as mon 'April' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 5 as mon 'May' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 6 as mon 'June' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 7 as mon 'July' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 8 as mon 'August' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 9 as mon 'September' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 10 as mon 'October' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 11 as mon 'November' AS
    MONTH
    UNION SELECT 12 as mon 'December' AS
    MONTH
    ) AS m
```

The simplest will be to create a separate table, and join with what you currently have ( `Kot_items` )
[From here](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/334766/select-query-to-results-all-12-months-even-if-data-not-exist)

Comment: How does this help if there's no rows with December dates in them?

Comment: k fine but i have only 3 month date in databases but if  month is not present then also i want to display all month not only a present month data in databases

Comment: you have transactions with no date set ( and no month ) but you still want to display the month name ? can you explain more  please ?

Comment: He wants to display results for all months in the year, even months that have no transactions in the table.

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT MONTHNAME(datefield) as monthname FROM tablename`

Comment: How does this help? His problem is that some months aren't in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.mon, m.month
FROM (
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Jan' as month
UNION    
SELECT 2 as mon, 'Feb' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Mar' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Apr' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'May' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Jun' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Jul' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Aug' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Sep' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Oct' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Nov' as month
UNION    
SELECT 1 as mon, 'Dec' as month  
) AS m
LEFT JOIN Kot_items k ON m.month = k.month(Tran_date)
```