# Get Count 0 instead of NULL MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a query that counts the number of posts in a month with a certain tag, but obviously my `WHERE` won't return anything if there are no posts.  The problem with that, I have overlayed on the chart another query that shows ALL posts, not just the ones who meet these `WHERE` conditions.  The second query will typically have a result for every month.  How can I get this query to return zero if the result is null?  I've read a few of the answers here, but can't quite figure it out.

```sql
SELECT MONTHNAME(post_time) AS month, 
       COALESCE(Count(distinct p.post_id), 0) AS count 
FROM post.p 
INNER JOIN post_tag_map t ON ( p.post_id = t.knote_id ) 
WHERE t.post_id IN (23,24,49,54) 
/*these numbers are actually a variable, this is just an example*/  
AND p.post_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

I'm trying to show both Months and Posts from the beginning of time of the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to include rows with no match:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(post_time) AS month, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(distinct t.knote_id), 0) AS count 
FROM post AS p 
LEFT JOIN post_tag_map AS t 
ON p.post_id = t.knote_id AND t.post_id IN (23,24,49,54) 
WHERE p.post_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY month
```

Note that you have to put the `t` conditions in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`, when using `LEFT JOIN`; otherwise, they'd fail on the non-matching rows. And you have to count the column from `t`, so it will skip the null value for the non-matching row.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bfed/6)

Comment: This looked right, but it's still not returning anything for March (0 posts total, so that makes sense to me but not desired result).

Comment: You need to join with a table that contains the month. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130805/extract-all-month-in-one-coulmn-from-date/23131017#23131017 for a way to create it on the fly.

Comment: Ok. The same table does contain the months. They show up if i dont do the WHERE IN. If that makes sense.

Comment: There's no `WHERE IN` in my answer. I moved the `IN` condition to the `ON` clause to solve that problem.

Comment: Err - I meant...the table that contain the posts, there are posts from every month.  Just not necessarily those tagged with this particular tag (23,24,49,54).  If I run this query without the `IN`, those months show.  I was wondering if I could do that without creating a separate table just for the months.

Comment: It should work with `IN`. The `LEFT JOIN` means that all the rows in the `posts` table will be returned, even if they have no match in `post_tag_map`. Can you make a sqlfiddle showing what you're doing?

Comment: I forgot the `GROUP BY` clause. I've added it, and added a sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: Sure, here is my exact table structure, and my original query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf1bb/7

You'll see that it works perfectly when all months are represented in the posts with this tag.  However, I want it to show 0 instead of NULL when a tag has not been used in a month. 

But when we don't have a post in March, it doesn't show up: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b6487/1

I really appreciate your help, @Barmar.

Comment: You're using an INNER JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN. Don't you understand the difference, and why it's important for what you're doing?

Comment: I do.  I just used my original query in the SQLFiddle to demonstrate my case.  

With the latest modification to your post, it appears to be functioning the way I intended.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Also your fiddle didn't have any posts in March. See this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4880b/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  ISNULL(amount,0) function:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(post_time) AS month, 
ISNULL(Count(distinct p.post_id), 0) AS count 
FROM post.p 
INNER JOIN post_tag_map t ON ( p.post_id = t.knote_id ) 
WHERE t.post_id IN (23,24,49,54) 
/*these numbers are actually a variable, this is just an example*/  
AND p.post_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```